# Wordpress do_shortcode и $atts['shortcode'] внутри

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, пытаюсь вывести shortcode, но не получается. Надеюсь кто-нибудь укажет на решение.

Цель: Мне нужен textfield в Visual Composer, чтобы я мог добавлять уникальные shortcode'ы для каждой из моих кнопок оплаты.

Вот textfield который я создал:

```
array(
        'type'          => 'textfield',
        'heading'       => esc_html__('Shortcode', 'softing'),
        'param_name'    => 'shortcode',
        'edit_field_class' => 'vc_col-sm-4',
        ),
```

Вот shortcode  который я вставляю: *[purchase_link id="3839" text="Add To Cart" style="button" color="orange"]*

Если я вывожу этот shortcode через:

```
$out .= '<div class="pricing-box-shortcode">'.'<div class="#pricing-box-shortcode">'.do_shortcode($atts['shortcode']).'</div>'.'</div>';
```

То получаю такой результат - моя главная проблема, которую я пытаюсь решить:
[image]

Заметил что если я не использую *$atts['shortcode']* а просто вставляю голый shortcode в do_shortcode()  - всё срабатывает нормально:

```
do_shortcode([purchase_link id="3839" text="Add To Cart" style="button" color="orange"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Судя по результату то у вас в `$atts['shortcore']` экранированные данные и так же ваш шорткод выводит данные, а не возвращает как это должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется у вас здесь банально не хватает одинарных кавычек

```php
do_shortcode('[purchase_link id="3839" text="Add To Cart" style="button" color="orange"]');
```

Вот мой пример [шорткод](https://gist.github.com/vevgeniy85/3ce7e11f760da6bedc93e9656eb8d501)а с атрибутами

```php
// Add Shortcode
function akea_banner_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'img' => 'https://dummyimage.com/1920x200/ccc/fff.jpg',
            'alt' => '',
            'url' => '',
            'target' => '_self',
            'width' => '100%',
            'height' => 'auto',
        ),
        $atts,
        'banner'
    );

    $alt = ($atts['alt'] != '') ? ' alt="' . $atts['alt'] . '"' : ' alt=""';
    $urlStyles = ' style="display: block;"';
    $blockStyles = ' style="margin-bottom: 30px;"';

    $output = '<div class="akea-banner-shortcode"' . $blockStyles . '>';
    if ($atts['url'] != '') {
        $output .= '<a ' . $urlStyles . ' href="' . $atts['url'] . '" target="' . $atts['target'] . '">';
    }
    $output .= '<img src="' . $atts['img'] . '"' . $alt . ' width="' . $atts['width'] . '"' . ' height="' . $atts['height'] . '">';
    if ($atts['url'] != '') {
        $output .= '</a>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';

    // Return code
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'akea_banner_shortcode' );
```

```php
[banner img="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/banner_blog.png" alt="banner" url="https://domain.ru/" target="_blank"]
```